# Squash all UIDs automatically, without "all_squash"

Tags: debian, permissions, nfs

I have a pair of Debian stable boxes sharing `/home` over NFS. The server used to serve LTSP workstations and has had a long running NFS configuration that never gave me any trouble.

The LTSP project ended, I got a new laptop, connected to the same NFS server, and saw no problems until the laptop died. I then got an old laptop out of mothballs, set it up with identical UIDs, mounted `/home` and discovered all the files in `/home` are owned by `nobody`.

Apparently, since I last was active in setting up NFS (not just using my stable setup) `nfs4` and `all_squash` have become options. I checked my exports file, and everything looks fine: `all_squash` is not specified anywhere and it is not the default.

What did I miss?